# How do I make my alien species be able to handle molecules of either chirality?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, mythical-creatures, biochemistry

I want to design an alien species whose physiology is capable of metabolizing substances regardless of whether their [chemical chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)) is levorotatory or dextrorotatory. Is this scientifically possible, and if so, what would be required?

Comment: Do you want their metabolism to break down both kinds of molecules (that would be relatively easy), or do you want them to incorporate both kinds into their bodies without change (that should be harder)?

Comment: Possible, or expected to happen? For example, you would need an additional genes to be able to burn L-Glucose. And additional set to create it. This is hug cost, evolutionary, and also it would be surprising to happen. And it does not provide a plant with any benefit, one kind of glucose can do the job.

Comment: @Alexander I want them able to break down both kinds of molecules.

Comment: @Mołot: Possible, of course. The fact that homochirality is a thing here on Earth answers the question of "is it expected to happen?" already, IMO.

Comment: Which molecules? Some are already present both ways! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carvone

Comment: @MarqFJA87 - so, suppose your species utilize L-molecules directly. Then they can develop enzymes that break down D-molecules and use them as fuel.

Comment: Some life forms already incorporate D-amino acids along with the normal L-ones (ask your nearest friendly *E.coli* about this), so limited heterochirality is already a part of Earth biology, and can have evolutionary value (the classic D-Ala-D-Ala linkage of peptidoglycan is an example of this -- if it were an L-amino-acid linkage, then the bacteria's wall would just get eaten up by whatever proteases were roaming around)

Comment: @JDługosz: I'm talking in general, man. Consider how we humans can't derive any nutritional value from dextro-chiral substances. Hell, those could easily make us sick!

Comment: @Alexander: It's as simple as that? BTW, if you're posing that as an answer, then why are you posting it in a comment?

Comment: @Shalvenay: Again, not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but if you're answering the question, why do it in a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: If you have an environment in which both chiralities are prevalent, why wouldn't they develop the use of both - use it for laterally symmetric structures!

Answer (score 4):

Its not going to be a problem. Humans and animals already have some ability to digest D-isomers of amino acids (though results significantly vary from one amino acid to another). In a world where D-isomeres are widely available, it's logical to assume that animals would have the necessary enzymes to process not some, but all D-isomers.

This is all assuming that the species of this world, like here on Earth, would have a strong preference for one type of enantiomers. So, some species would like D-isomers, some L-isomers, and they can be a viable food source for each other.

[Study abstract 1](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00021369.1967.10858772)

[Study abstract 2](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf990080u?journalCode=jafcau)